# Matrix $X$ positivity for given formula $(I \otimes L + L \otimes I) \mbox{vec}(X) = \mbox{vec}(C)$ and matrices $L, C > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

In control theory, the Sylvester transformation of equation $AX + XB = C$ into $(I \otimes A + B^\intercal \otimes I) \mbox{vec}(X) = \mbox{vec}(C)$ appears oftentimes. This made me ask myself about the positivity property of matrix $X$: given matrices $A = B = L$ and $L>0$, as well as matrix $C>0$, is the matrix $J$ given by formula $I \otimes L + L \otimes I$, is matrix $J > 0$ as well?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it